# How to tackle a research journal - level course in Lie Theory and Representation Theory?

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am taking a course in Lie Theory and Theory of Representations this year, where starting from the second lecture, Lie Theory is heavily bundled with Theory of Representations.

It is pretty much a series of theorems, lemmas, corollaries, etc., and I hardly understand any of it, because it is quite abstract, dense, and stacks up very quickly. It seems that the course is research journal level, not graduate level.

I have a high GPA, and did not have issues with courses before.

What would be a good strategy to tackle a course like this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "research journal" level course, and what you describe sounds like every graduate course in mathematics I ever took. Can you clarify? Do you have the necessary background for the course?

Comment: Well, I have completed all of the required prerequisites, but I am not 100% sure I have nothing missing besides that. This is an advanced graduate level course, but I'm taking another one without the necessary prerequisites, but that one is easy for me just like the rest. By research journal level, I mean the type of content you might deal with after Ph.D. in Math coursework.